# On undefinability of well-orderings in $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, infinitary-logic, infinitary-sentences

It is a well-known theorem that well-orderings can not be characterized in $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$.
In particular, if $\psi$ is an $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$-sentence in a vocabulary $\tau$ that contains a binary symbol $<$ and $<$ is a linear order in all models of $\psi$, then either $<$ is a well-ordering of order-type $\alpha<\omega_1$, or otherwise, $\psi$  has models where < is not well-ordered.

The proofs that I am aware of produce a model $N$ of size $\aleph_1$ such that $\mathbb{Q}$ embeds into $<^N$.

Is the following generalization of the above theorem true? 
Let $\psi$ be an $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$-sentence  and $\psi$ has a model (of any size) where $<$ is not well-ordered. If $\psi$ as a model of size $\kappa$, then there is a model of size $\kappa$ where $<$ is not well-ordered.

My conjecture is "yes", but I could not find a proof in the literature. The main obstacle is that the methods used to produce the $\aleph_1$-sized model do not generalize to arbitrary $\kappa$.

Comment: I suppose that you want to assume that the domain of $<$ is uncountable in your model of size $\kappa$, since otherwise the answer is easily "no". Do you want to assume that the domain of $<$ is the entire model, or just of size $\kappa$?

Comment: @PaulLarson: Let's assume that the domain of $<$ is the entire model. If we can deal with this case, then I think we can deal with the case where the domain of $<$ is a subset that may have different cardinality than the entire model. Also, I reworded my question to avoid your "easily no" possibility.

Comment: Remind me, please, $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$ has Löwenheim-Skolem, or completeness? (or neither, or a partial property of some?)

Comment: @Asaf It has downward Löwenheim-Skolem. I'm not sure what you mean by completeness. The logic is (for countable theories) complete wrt a nice infinitary calculus. There is no question of effectiveness, as already the number of sentences is continuum.

Comment: @Emil: Completeness in the usual sense, provable if and only if satisfiable. But I think I probably meant to ask about compactness.

Comment: It's not compact.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I believe there is a completeness theorem for (fragments of) $L_{\omega_1\omega}$, though, due to Barwise (but I don't have the book at hand).

Comment: This is a bit tangential, but $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$ (even $L_{\omega_1,\omega}(Q)$) admits a completeness theorem.  See  Barwise's "The role of the omitting types theorem in infinitary logic".

Comment: The completeness theorem for $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$ is actually attributed to Karp in Keisler's "Model Theory for Infinitary Logic".

Comment: I think the question has to be modified to avoid examples that say things like "either $\phi$ holds or the domain of $<$ has size $1$", where $\phi$ is some sentence that be be satisfied only by models of cardinality less than $\kappa$. Maybe it should say something like : if $\psi$ has a model for which $\kappa$ embeds into the interpretation of $<$, then it has a model of cardinality $\kappa$ whose interpretation of $<$ is illfounded.

Comment: @PaulLarson: I think you are worried about two-cardinal models, where the model has size $\kappa$ and the domain of $<$ has size $\lambda\le\kappa$. Is that right? If so, I think the easiest rewording is to assume that the domain of $<$ is the whole model.